# GFI does not reset

Tags: receptacle

GFI outlet stopped working. I replaced the outlet, but the GFI outlet will not reset and  doesn't work. But the two outlets wired to it do.

Comment: Can you provide photos of the inside of the box with the GFCI in it?

Comment: What is plugged into it?  Do you know the difference between `LINE` and `LOAD` and do you have anything connected to `LOAD`?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you have the load and line wires mixed up. If an outlet is in series with a GFCI then the only way the next outlet in the chain would work is if the GFCI outlet was reset, allowing the electricity to pass down stream. If the line and load are swapped, the outlets down stream will have power, but the GFCI won't reset. Swap your line and load!!